# Angular : TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null when subscribe()

Tags: angular, http, angular-services

I'm getting this response when making an HTTP request in service:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at eval (http.js:123)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.lazyInit (http.js:117)
    at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:265)
    at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:368)
    at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (http.js:2172)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:162)
    at eval (subscribeToObservable.js:16)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:6)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:127)
ALERT!!!!!
```

**I subscribe the HTTP request when loading my component:**

```
export class TasksComponent implements OnInit {
  currentUser:any;
  username:string=null;
  constructor(private usersService:UsersService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.username=localStorage.getItem('currentUsername');
    console.log(this.username);
    this.usersService.getUserByUsername(this.username)
      .subscribe(data=>{
        console.log(data);
        this.currentUser=data;
      },err=>{
        console.log(err);
        console.log("ALERT!!!!! ");
      })
  }
}
```

**UsersService:**

```
//for getting a user by its username
getUserByUsername(username:string){
  if(this.jwtToken==null) this.authenticationService.loadToken();
    return this.http.get(this.host+"/userByUsername?username="+username
          , {headers:new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.jwtToken})}
    );
}
```

**How I stored the username in the localStorage so I can use it to find the user with all his properties :**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  private host:string="http://localhost:8080";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient){}
  login(user){
    localStorage.setItem('currentUsername', user.username);
    return this.http.post(this.host+"/login",user, {observe:'response'});
  }
}
```

**[My localStorage after a Log In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9rly.png)**

Knowing that the method is working in the back-end like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srNLr.png)
what do you think the problem is? is it a service injection problem or is it about dependencies, or another thing?

**EDIT**
The loadToken function:

```
loadToken(){
    this.jwtToken=localStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log(this.jwtToken);
    let jwtHelper=new JwtHelper();
    this.roles=jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.jwtToken).roles;
    return this.jwtToken;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, hard to say, could be a CORS problem, since your web app is probably hosted at another port(4200). Or maybe loadToken() is asynchronous and you still call the get-request without the auth-token. You should check network requests in your browser and see if you get data from backend on that request...

Comment: it's not a CORS problem because i run other requests(GET,POST,OPTIONS...) and they work fine , i'll add the loadToken() function in the question. and i'v checked Network in my browser and i don't get data from backend.

Comment: what is the HTTP-Code? 200? Btw. empty response is a signal for CORS issue...

Comment: for login link it's 200

Comment: no, for the request, where you have problems

Comment: the link doesn't appear in the Network

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since you don't see the request in the network-panel of your browser, it seems that you don't send the request. This is probably because you don't set the token in this line:

```
if(this.jwtToken==null) this.authenticationService.loadToken();
```

the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at eval (http.js:123)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.lazyInit (http.js:117)
    at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:265)
    at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:368)
```

indicates, that your Header (`Authorization`) is `null` and therefore can't be read.

try to change the line to:

```
if(this.jwtToken==null) this.jwtToken = this.authenticationService.loadToken();
```

now you should see your request in the network panel

or maybe you just want to check the token on the `authenticationService` itself:

```
if(this.authenticationService.jwtToken==null) this.authenticationService.loadToken();
    return this.http.get(this.host+"/userByUsername?username="+username
      , {headers:new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.authenticationService.jwtToken})}
);
```